# Hyper-V monitor virtual machine disk activity

Tags: performance, hyper-v

How can I get the number of bytes read from/written into the physical disk of the host system by Hyper-V virtual machines?

Comment: Probably a question for ServerFault?

Comment: @ewall - Please don't add "belongs-on-" tags. Add a comment if you can't vote to close.

Answer (score 2):

You can try a commercial tool called [ApexSQL VM Monitor](https://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_vm_monitor.aspx). I can mention that it has a lot of predefined metrics for inspecting hypervisor and virtual machine performance, such as disk read/write rate for both host and virtual machine.

It also provides graphical presentation of monitored data and has alerting ability so you can be just-on-time alerted when some of the hardware resources or virtual machines is poorly performing or utilizing too much resources.

Beside this tool, you may also check out other commercial tools like tools from ManagEngine, Paessler or [SolarWinds](https://www.solarwinds.com/topics/vmware-performance-monitoring-tools)

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you can always use each hosted machine's own built-in performance monitoring, such as [Perfmon for Windows clients](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/HealthCheck/GettingStarted.htm).

However, the hosting Hyper-V server also exposes a ton of counters not only for its own OS, but also for each hosted machine. For more info, see articles [here](http://searchservervirtualization.techtarget.com/tip/0,289483,sid94_gci1342608_mem1,00.html?ShortReg=1&mboxConv=searchServerVirtualization_RegActivate_Submit&) and [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc768535%28BTS.10%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can use typeperf from the command line

```
typeperf \PhysicalDisk(*)\Disk Write Bytes/sec
```

you may need to enable disk performance counters through

```
diskperf -y
```

Some variants of windows server use slightly different names. If the above doesn't work you can use:

```
typeperf -q | find /I "Physical"
```

Comment: Used `diskperf -y` in Admin command prompt on Hyper-V virtual machine and voila! Disk activity appeared in Task Manager.